# Error on first page load working with instantSearch.js and SvelteKit

Tags: sveltekit

I am getting this error when I run npm run dev in my project.

```
Unexpected token 'export'
C:\Users\rcap\Desktop\bot-imoveis\node_modules\instantsearch.js\es\widgets\index.js:1
export { default as clearRefinements } from './clear-refinements/clear-refinements';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:190:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:195:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:331:24)
```

My instantSearch component:

```svelte
<script>
    // add  typesense search

    import instantsearch from 'instantsearch.js'
    import { searchBox, hits } from 'instantsearch.js/es/widgets'
    import TypesenseInstantSearchAdapter from 'typesense-instantsearch-adapter'
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'
    import { browser } from '$app/env'

    let search = {
        q: '',
        query_by: 'name, description, address'
    }
    console.log(search)

    onMount(() => {
        const typesenseInstantsearchAdapter = new TypesenseInstantSearchAdapter({
            server: {
                apiKey: 'MY_API_KEY', // Be sure to use an API key that only allows search operations
                nodes: [
                    {
                        host: 'MY_HOST',
                        port: '443',
                        protocol: 'https'
                    }
                ],
                cacheSearchResultsForSeconds: 2 * 60 // Cache search results from server. Defaults to 2 minutes. Set to 0 to disable caching.
            },
            // The following parameters are directly passed to Typesense's search API endpoint.
            //  So you can pass any parameters supported by the search endpoint below.
            //  query_by is required.
            additionalSearchParameters: {
                query_by: 'name,description,location,mode'
            }
        })
        if (browser) {
            const searchClient = typesenseInstantsearchAdapter.searchClient

            const search = instantsearch({
                searchClient,
                indexName: 'listings'
            })
            search.addWidgets([
                searchBox({
                    container: '#searchbox',
                    showSubmit: false,
                    showReset: false,
                    placeholder: 'Buscar... ',
                    searchAsYouType: true,
                    autofocus: false
                }),

                hits({
                    container: '#hits',
                    templates: {
                        item(item) {
                            return `
                            <div class="" >
                                <a href="/category/all/${item.id}"/"${item.url}>${instantsearch.highlight({
                                attribute: 'name',
                                hit: item
                            })}</a>
                        
                            </div>
                        `
                        }
                    }
                })
            ])

            search.start()
        }
        const searchInput = document.querySelector('.ais-SearchBox-input')
        // add event listener to search input
        searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            search.q = e.target.value
            console.log(search.q)
            // show ishits if search input is > 0
            if (search.q !== '') {
                document.querySelector('.ais-Hits').classList.add('show-hits')
            }
            // hide ishits if search input is 0
            else if (search.q === '') {
                document.querySelector('.ais-Hits').classList.remove('show-hits')
            }
        })
    })
</script>

<div id="searchbox" />
<div id="hits" />
```

It is easier to see in my REPL:
https://svelte.dev/repl/465e1020d5a94be5a93d733b57146f1a?version=3.49.0

If I reload the page, everything works perfectly.

My svelte.config.js:

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto'

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        vite: {
            server: {
                fs: true
            }
        },
        adapter: adapter()
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['typesense-instantsearch-adapter', 'instantsearch.js']
        }
    }
}

export default config
```

I am also getting this error:

> `<SearchBar>` is not a valid SSR component. You may need to review your build config to ensure that dependencies are compiled, rather than imported as pre-compiled modules

I just need to fix it to finish my project. Need Help!

Comment: Maybe try to dynamically import the `instantsearch` stuff inside `onMount`..?

Comment: Does note works.

Comment: I follow this issue https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-components-svelte/issues/595 and it seems to have worked.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error ```No adapter specified
See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters to learn how to configure your app to run on the platform of your choosing
Error! No Output Directory named "public" found after the Build completed. You can configure the Output Directory in your Project Settings.``` when deploying on Vercel

Comment: My svelte.congif.js: ```import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto'

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
 kit: {
  vite: {
   server: {
    fs: true
   },
   optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['instantsearch.js']
   }
  }
 },
 adapter: adapter()
}

export default config
```

Comment: I don't understand why it is now showing this error.